# Check NSString for specific date format

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsdate

I have a NSString and I need to check that it is in a this specific format MM/DD/YY. I then need to convert that to a NSDate. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Sidenote - I have searched around and people suggest using RegEx, I have never used this and am unclear about it generally. Can anyone point me to a good resource/explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `NSDateFormatter` for both tasks. If you can convert the string to a date then it is in the correct format (and you already have the result).

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *strDate1 = @"02/09/13";
NSString *strDate2 = @"0123/234/234";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
NSDate *dateFormat1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate1];
NSDate *dateFormat2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate2];

NSLog(@"%@", dateFormat1); // prints 2013-09-02 00:00:00 +0000
NSLog(@"%@", dateFormat2); // prints (null)
```

So you will know when it's not formatted correctly if the NSDate is nil. Here's the link to the docs if you need more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1

Comment: @lnafziger is right. Make sure to keep that in mind if you use something similar to what I put above.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a late answer, but it is impossible to always guarantee that a string is in this particular date format.

A date formatter, a regex, or even a human can not verify certain dates, because we don't know if the user is entering "mm/DD/yy" or "DD/mm/yy".  It is common in some places to enter the day of the month first, while in other areas you enter the month first.  So if they enter "09/06/2013" do they mean "September 6th" or the "9th of June"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple function for anyone searching for a simple solution.

```
- (BOOL) isTheStringDate: (NSString*) theString
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:theString];

    if (dateFromString !=nil) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You have to change the formatter below to match the formatting your date is using.

```
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```